# How to check email address exists

Tags: java, email, email-validation

I work for a public university and we have an online admission application that requires applicants to provide referees' email address. many applicants (they are kids!!) spell email address wrong. How can we check if an email address actually exists and will receive our email?

Comment: Hi there, please read the [ask] page to help you improve your question.  from the sounds of it (so far), this may not be the forum for it - However, feel free to edit it and add the missing bits. Perhaps we can be of help

Answer (score 2):

I think actually the only way to check if an email address exists is sending a mail to it. Even if exists, you don't know if mail will be received (for example a soft bound may occur).

Another thing that you can do in java is to write a regular expression just to check if email string has a pattern to be considered an email (for example having @, having a domain, having a dot, and so on).

Comment: Instead of writing regexps on your own, you could use commons' validator - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html, it handles the invalid TLDNs and other similar stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to implement email validation for the referees if this is important to you. You would send them an email with a validation link and a message explaining why they are receiving the email, keep track of any bounced emails sent this way, and then send them to a form once the validation link is clicked to verify their address.

Comment: This is the best way, because it also confirms that the email address actually belongs to them.